# Azure Function apps or Web API?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

From what I know about Azure Functions, and serverless computing in general, is that it provides the benefit of not needing to pay for a server that is constantly running. I.E. you only pay for the compute that was used.

In my case, I am already paying for servers to host a web application. Would it not make sense to use those same servers to host a backend API?

My guess is that the performance of the web application would take a hit, but aside from that, are there any other reasons why the function apps would make sense over a web API?

Answer (score 1):

Another great benefit is to use the native bindings. So rather than you write the code in order to pull data, they are actually pushed to your function on an event based approach.